# Random odds in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

Okay, so let's say I store some of my data like this,

```
var thisList = {
    "items":[
        {"name":"Item1", "image":"/img/item1", "chance":0.25},
        {"name":"Item2", "image":"/img/item2", "chance":0.25},
        {"name":"Item3", "image":"/img/item3", "chance":0.50}
    ]           
}
```

Now I'd like to create a function that randomly picks a item out of this list with the chances being 25% of getting [0], another 25% of getting [1] and a 50% chance of getting [2]!

Is this possible? If so, how'd I do this?

Kind regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually play it like this, tou generate a number between 0 and 100 and then you cycle on each element and sum the chance to check if it is between the value or not:

```js
var thisList = {
    "items":[
        {"name":"Item1", "image":"/img/item1", "chance":0.25},
        {"name":"Item2", "image":"/img/item2", "chance":0.25},
        {"name":"Item3", "image":"/img/item3", "chance":0.50}
    ]           
};

function getRandom(){
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  console.log("The number is: " + rnd);
  var counter = 0;
  for(i=0;i<thisList.items.length;i++)
  {
    counter += thisList.items[i].chance * 100;
    if(counter > rnd){
      console.log(thisList.items[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
}

getRandom();
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to control even with a variant chance you can do this:

```js
var thisList = {
    "items":[
        {"name":"Item1", "image":"/img/item1", "chance":0.25},
        {"name":"Item2", "image":"/img/item2", "chance":0.25},
        {"name":"Item3", "image":"/img/item3", "chance":0.50}
    ]           
};

function getRandom(){
  var sum = 0;
  for(i=0;i<thisList.items.length;i++)
  {
    sum += thisList.items[i].chance;
  }
  var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sum * 100));
  console.log("The number is: " + rnd);
  var counter = 0;
  for(i=0;i<thisList.items.length;i++)
  {
    counter += thisList.items[i].chance * 100;
    if(counter > rnd){
      console.log(thisList.items[i]);
      break;
    }
  }
}

getRandom();
```

Comment: This would work as long as it adds up to 1.00, am I correct?

Comment: @MartijnEbbens Yes it does. But i have updated my answer with another version, and now it works even when the chance sum > 1.00

Comment: I will always keep my chances rounding up to 1.00 or 100%, thanks for the handy dandy code tho! Seems to be working quite well!

Comment: The factors of 100 in this are completely unnecessary, but otherwise it's the algorithm I was describing

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the *cumulative* sum of all odds seen so far in the array.   With the sample data you've given those values would be 0.25, 0.5, 1.0

Then given a random number in the range [0, 1), just pick the first entry where the cumulative value is less than that number.

Here's an example implementation:

```
const pickRandom = (() => {
    let target = Math.random(), total = 0.0;
    return (e, i, a) => {
        total += e.chance;
        return target < total;
    }
});

let picked = thisList.items.find(pickRandom());
```

The `pickRandom` function needs to be called exactly *once* per round, and returns a function that encapsulates the state necessary to accumulate the chances seen so far, and the random number that is to be used.

That function then becomes the predicate used by `Array.prototype.find` to extract the appropriate random item.

Comment: All chances should always add up to 1.0 | 100%, so you'd say if I'd where to take this list,

`var thisList = {
    "items":[
        {"name":"Item1", "image":"/img/item1", "chance":0.25},
        {"name":"Item2", "image":"/img/item2", "chance":0.25},
        {"name":"Item3", "image":"/img/item3", "chance":0.50}
    ]           
}`

and then I'd get a random number using,

`var random = Math.random();`

and then check if the number is less than it's chance

`for(x /*Loop*/){
      if(thisList.items[x].chance <= random){
          //var
      }
}`

That would work?

Comment: No, not quite - the cumulative odds bit is what allows the random selection to pick the appropriate value in the range [0, 1) with the appropriate distribution.   I've a meeting to go to so don't have time to flesh this out with code just now, but if you just start from 0 and add up the chances seen, you  can just return as soon as the random number is lower than the cumulative chance.

Comment: If you still need code in another hour or so I'll have time to add some then